# How to stop list items breaking to a new line

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want the images in my list items to stay on the same line as the browser window resizes and not to break onto a new line. Is this possible? I tried using nowrap as I saw some other people mentioning it but it didn't work for me.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;/*removes white space*/
  margin: 60px auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 2400px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
}

.carousel li{
  float: left;
}

.carousel li img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#next{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#prev{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img_cont{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.active{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div id="next">
  </div> 
  <div id="prev">
  </div> 
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `li` items `inline-block`s  and add `overflow-x: visible; white-space: nowrap;` to `.carousel` in order to have all `li`s in one line

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  /*removes white space*/
  margin: 60px auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 2400px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.carousel li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img_cont {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.active {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div id="next">
  </div>
  <div id="prev">
  </div>
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.carousel{
  display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;/*removes white space*/
  margin: 60px auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 2400px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
}

.carousel li{
  float: left;
}

.carousel li img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#next{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#prev{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img_cont{
  width: 10%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.active{
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div id="next">
  </div> 
  <div id="prev">
  </div> 
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

is this you want?